# Android adding JSONObject to JSONArray with Key

Tags: android, json

Hi I'm trying to make an alphabetised list with headers so i want an array of JSONObjects with the key of "B" for example inside that object i'm going to be adding an array of JSONObjects that contains contacts whose name begins with the key or "B"

does anyone know how to add a JSONObject to a JSONArray with a key? so that i can retrieve specific Objects

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To reach your requirement your JSON object should like this

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "name":"aaa"
      },
      {
         "name":"aba"
      }
   ],
   "B":[
      {
         "name":"bbb"
      },
      {
         "name":"bba"
      }
   ]
}
```

A pseudo implementation for above Object would look like this:

```
//Maint list object
    JSONObject objMainList = new JSONObject();

    //prepare item array for "A"
    JSONArray arrForA = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject itemA = new JSONObject();
    itemA.put("name", "aaa");
    arrForA.put(itemA);

  //prepare item array for "B"
    JSONArray arrForB = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject itemB = new JSONObject();
    itemB.put("name", "bbb");
    arrForB.put(itemB);

    //Finally add item arrays for "A" and "B" to main list with key
    objMainList.put("A", arrForA);
    objMainList.put("B", arrForB);
```

UPDATE : to check if "A" or "B".. is exists or not

```
if(objMainList.has("A")){

    }
```

Comment: do you know how i would detect if JSONArry arrForA already existed in the JSONObject so i don't keep adding multiple versions

Answer (score 2):

Try out this way:

```
{"Contacts": //JSONObject
  {
    "B"://JSONArray..
    [
        {"ContactName":sdfsdf,"ID":900,"Number":1368349}, 
        {"ContactName":adsdfd,"ID":1900,"Number":136856},  
         {"ContactName":adglkhdofg,"ID":600,"Number":136845}
   ],
  "C":[
         {"ContactName":alkghoi,"ID":900,"Number":1368349},
         {"ContactName":wetete,"ID":1900,"Number":136856}, 
         {"ContactName":dfhtfh,"ID":600,"Number":136845}
     ]
      .....//and so on.. 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the functionalities of a map as it seems to me. You can then use an array of objects that behave like a Map.Entry.
Something like :

```
[{key:a,value:<some-value>},...]
```

Moreover : why not serialize you data as a list of contacts and add the 'sorted' behavior (using an alphabetic index) programmatically ?